# Desahabilitar CORS Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, laravel, cors

quiero dehacerme de los `CORS` entiendo la seguridad y todo eso ,pero a mi no me sirve en este caso, llevo tratandolo toda la semana y nada, he intentado de todas las formas posibles pero no me deja.

Todo el rato restringido por `CORS` y todo eso, quiero desahilitarlo por completo, que dea acceso libre a mi sistema.

**TODAS LAS FORMAS DE INTENTO**

**bootstrap.php , api.php**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, *");
```

**Middleware**

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    return $next($request)
      ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE")
      ->header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization"); 
  }
```

**cors.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
    | or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
    | in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
    |
    | To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
    |
    */
    'paths' => ['api/*','api/admin/*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['POST', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT', 'OPTIONS', '*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*', '*', '*','*, *', '*, *, *', '*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['X-Custom-Header', 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests', 'csrftoken', 'x-csrf-token', 'CSRFToken', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN','Access-Control-Allow-Origin','content-type', 'accept', '*'],
    'exposed_headers' => ['x-custom-response-header'],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
];
```

Parece que es cuando la peticion es con un usuario logueado, si el usuario no esta logueado no ocurre ese problema,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.post(web + "/api/admin/all").then(res => {
        Object.keys(res).forEach((key, pos) => {
            try{
                $("#" + key).val(key == "ptep" ? eval(res[key]):res[key]);
            }catch(er){
                console.log(er);
            };
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Poner header en un middleware o en bootstrap.php, creo que es medio cogido por los pelos. Por defecto viene algo como esto: `'paths' => ['api/*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => false,` Eso aceptaría cualquier petición a tu api desde cualquier dominio y dando respuesta por defecto. Prueba a ver

Comment: @gaidyjg no funciona, por eso metí código para desabilitarlo manualmente,

Comment: Limpiaste la cache de configuración después de hacer los cambios?